# Translate sql query to linq so I can use it in foreach loop

Tags: c#, sql, linq, foreach, entity-framework-core

I have an sql query that I want to translate to LINQ so I can access the h.name and a.ActivityName in a foreach loop

```
  SELECT al.HamsterID, 
         h.name, 
         a.ActivityName, 
         al.Time
    FROM ActivityLog al 
    JOIN Activities a ON a.id = al.ActivityID 
    JOIN Hamsters h ON h.HamsterID = al.HamsterID
ORDER BY HamsterID
```

Currently it returns that Hamster and Activity are null which are properties in ActivityLog

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: I am still looking online for some solutions. I've tried the .Join method but I can't get it to  work

Comment: SQL can't be translated into LINQ. It's possible to write LINQ that more or less *reproduces* the SQL query but that requires knowledge of the LINQ building blocks, none of which are disclosed here.

Comment: Are you using Entity?  If do you have a context dbContext and which has a list of tables (classes) and and each class has rows. So a table would be dbContext.ActivityLog. Your for loop would look like : foreach(var row in dbContext.ActivityLog)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using database first, and assuming you have defined the primary/foreign key relationships in the database objects, EF will generate the class files which encode the parent/child relationships. So the EF-generated **Hamster** class will have an **ActivityLog** property, the **ActivityLog** class will have **Hamsters** and **Activites** properties, etc. If you're using code first you need to do that yourself in the database object class definitions and/or the DbContext.OnModelCreating method. So that takes care of the SQL **SELECT** and **FROM** clauses. The **ORDER BY** clause in the SQL would become **.OrderBy(x => x.HamsterID)** in Linq.

You can see the SQL that is generated and executed by linq if you use the DBContext log property to write to the console or to a log file, etc..

If the Hamster and Activity properties of the ActivityLog instance are null, then you should check that the values of **ActivityLog.HamsterID** and **ActivityLog.ActivityID** exist in the **Hamster** table and **Activity** table respectively. If they do, then there is a problem with your code, either in the the database object class definitions and/or the DbContext.OnModelCreating  method.